# How do you deploy an application to VMWare?

Tags: java, vmware-vsphere

I have an enterprise java container called Karaf that I would like to test on a VMWare node. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything on the web that describes the process of how to deploy an application to a VMWare node. Can anyone assist by either telling me or pointing me to a tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

You would deploy your application to a VMWare node in the same way that you would deploy it to a physical node - at the OS level they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the same. You should follow vmware tuning guide for jvm such as reserve the memory you need, large memory page etc. Google for vmware jvm tuning and search at vmware.com